# Cleaning up the #AzureAD and Microsoft account overlap

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal

[#Azure AD and Microsoft Account Overlap](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Active-Directory-Identity/Cleaning-up-the-AzureAD-and-Microsoft-account-overlap/ba-p/245105?OCID=AID681541_aff_7795_1243925&irgwc=1&epi=je6NUbpObpQ-I0FQDo55KcWu2MZVCjl.vA&ranEAID=je6NUbpObpQ&tduid=(ir__xkjeuqydjgaqhid63sg1snixsf2xk9mwk6wqbjj900)(7795)(1243925)(je6NUbpObpQ-I0FQDo55KcWu2MZVCjl.vA)()&irclickid=_xkjeuqydjgaqhid63sg1snixsf2xk9mwk6wqbjj900&ranSiteID=je6NUbpObpQ-I0FQDo55KcWu2MZVCjl.vA&ranMID=43674)

Has there been any movement on this? I currently pay for O365 Business for my email, I would like to consolidate my personal Live account (used only for Xbox account) into my primary email (O365) but seems I cannot. Is there a future state that will allow this or shall I take my domain and move to a different paid email platform? Thought? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you cannot consolidate the personal live account into the O365 email for the time being, but you could use them side by side.

For the details, please read [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-do-i-merge-my-personal-and-work-microsoft-accounts-85fe5779-dbc8-4c81-abdb-214a3a7d17c6).

Comment: Thanks, but my question is geared toward an update for the link I added above... 

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Active-Directory-Identity/Cleaning-up-the-AzureAD-and-Microsoft-account-overlap/ba-p/245105?OCID=AID681541_aff_7795_1243925&irgwc=1&epi=je6NUbpObpQ-I0FQDo55KcWu2MZVCjl.vA&ranEAID=je6NUbpObpQ&tduid=(ir__xkjeuqydjgaqhid63sg1snixsf2xk9mwk6wqbjj900)(7795)(1243925)(je6NUbpObpQ-I0FQDo55KcWu2MZVCjl.vA)()&irclickid=_xkjeuqydjgaqhid63sg1snixsf2xk9mwk6wqbjj900&ranSiteID=je6NUbpObpQ-I0FQDo55KcWu2MZVCjl.vA&ranMID=43674